# hadoop load balancing

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have multiple different keys generated in the following format:

"71 1 2", "69 2 3", "68 5 6", etc.

But, I find that most of these pairs  go to same reducers.

Even if I implement a custom partitioner, the getNumPartitioner method, in which we use, hash_val % numReducers, mostly returns values, which group to few reducers loading them, whereas, other reducers remain free. 
, 
According to my understanding, we can use WritableComparator to sort the keys but cannot control keys to go to different reducers.

Is there a way to improve load balancing? Pls help.

I am attaching some code below to make my explanation clear:

```
String a = "71 1 2";
String b = "72 1 1";
String c = "70 1 3";

int hash_a = a.hashCode();
int hash_b = b.hashCode();
int hash_c = c.hashCode();

int part_a = hash_a % 10;
int part_b = hash_b % 10;
int part_c = hash_c % 10;

System.out.println("hash a: "+hash_a+" part_a: "+part_a);
System.out.println("hash b: "+hash_b+" part_b: "+part_b);
System.out.println("hash c: "+hash_c+" part_c: "+part_c);
```

Output:

hash a: 1620857277 part_a: 7
hash b: 1621780797 part_b: 7
hash c: 1619933757 part_c: 7

As we see different keys tend to map to same reducer.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Not aure why those hash codes are so similar, but I always use a prime number of reducers.

Comment: Why don't you use the default HashPartitioner ?

Comment: @Jugde, will try setting prime reducers to check for performance improvemnet.

Comment: @Razvan, even hash partitioner does not given even results..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot simply take the java modulus operation because sometimes hashcode might be negative and surely there isn't something called a negative partition. So you might probably take an absolute value.

Second here is a strong hash function which I found on the internet. Instead of the normal 32 bit int, it generates a 64bit long. Again this suffers from the problem of negative partitions too, but you can correct that for yourself.

```
private static long[] byteTable;
private static final long HSTART = 0xBB40E64DA205B064L;
private static final long HMULT = 7664345821815920749L;

private static long[] createLookupTable() {
byteTable = new long[256];
long h = 0x544B2FBACAAF1684L;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 31; j++) {
    h = (h >>> 7) ^ h;
    h = (h << 11) ^ h;
    h = (h >>> 10) ^ h;
  }
  byteTable[i] = h;
}
return byteTable;
}
public static long hash(String s) {
byte[] data = s.getBytes();
long h = HSTART;
final long hmult = HMULT;
final long[] ht = createLookupTable();
for (int len = data.length, i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  h = (h * hmult) ^ ht[data[i] & 0xff];
}
return h;
} 

public static void main(String[] args) {

String a = "71 1 2";
String b = "72 1 1";
String c = "70 1 3";

long hash_a = hash(a);
long hash_b = hash(b);
long hash_c = hash(c);

long part_a = hash_a % 10;
long part_b = hash_b % 10;
long part_c = hash_c % 10;

System.out.println("hash a: "+hash_a+" part_a: "+part_a);
System.out.println("hash b: "+hash_b+" part_b: "+part_b);
System.out.println("hash c: "+hash_c+" part_c: "+part_c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think, this will solve my problem.. will implement and see!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a data skew problem and you will need to be a little more clever in your partitioner. A few things you could try:

- Hadoop ships with a [MurmurHash](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/hash/MurmurHash.html) implementation. You can try using it in place of hashCode() in your partitioner and perhaps that will get you more even partitions.
- Maybe you need to look beyond hashing. Is there anything about how your keys are generated that you can exploit to get more even distribution? For example, on the key "71 1 2" can you split on the space and mod the first number (e.g. 71) by the number of partitions?

You didn't mention if some of the keys in your data were actually duplicates. If so, a [custom combiner](http://www.philippeadjiman.com/blog/2010/01/14/hadoop-tutorial-series-issue-4-to-use-or-not-to-use-a-combiner/) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure using a "better" hash function can help as the unbalanced distribution may due to the nature of the data you processed. For the same input, the hash function always gives same output.

Comment: The Hash Function given by Apurv did result in better load balancing